# convert an rdd of dictionary to df

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How can i make an pipelined rdd of dict into a dataframe in pyspark

```
[{'ACARS 20170507/20170506085012209001.rcv': 'QU SOUTA8X\r\n.BJSXCXA 060849\r\nM12\r\nFI CX731/AN B-LAN\r\nDT BJS HKG 060849 M63A\r\n-  OFF,V01,CX 731 20170506 1,VHHH,OMDB,0833,0849,----,  600', 'ACARS 20170507/20170502020906017001.rcv': 'QU SOUTA8X\r\n.BJSXCXA 020209\r\nM12\r\nFI KA876/AN B-LAB\r\nDT BJS HKG 020209 M11A\r\n-  OFF,V01,KA 876 20170502 1,VHHH,ZSPD,0149,0208,----,  294', 'ACARS 20170507/20170505050124358002.rcv': 'QU SOUTA8X\r\n.BKKXCXA 050501\r\nCFD\r\nFI CX690/AN B-LAJ\r\nDT BKK XSP 050501 C10A\r\n-  .1/WRN/DBN17D/WN1705050500  261707002SMOKE LAVATORY DET FAULT'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

The below snippet should work

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import Row
>>>
>>> data = [{'foo': 'bar', 'hello': 'world'}]
>>> rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
>>> df = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(**x)).toDF()

>>> df.show()
+---+-----+
|foo|hello|
+---+-----+
|bar|world|
+---+-----+
```

Comment: its returning the df as `ACARS 20170507/20170507235838492001.rcv: string, ACARS 20170507/20170507235911543001.rcv: string, ACARS 20170507/20170507235933392001.rcv: string, ACARS 20170507/20170507235957177001.rcv: string` the value part is showing as `string`

Comment: It seems that it doesn't work when  the length of RDDs is different.

Answer (score 0):

Start:

```
>>> a = [{'ACARS 20170507/20170506085012209001.rcv': 'QU SOUTA8X\r\n.BJSXCXA 060849\r\nM12\r\nFI CX731/AN B-LAN\r\nDT BJS HKG 060849 M63A\r\n-  OFF,V01,CX 731 20170506 1,VHHH,OMDB,0833,0849,----,  600', 'ACARS 20170507/20170502020906017001.rcv': 'QU SOUTA8X\r\n.BJSXCXA 020209\r\nM12\r\nFI KA876/AN B-LAB\r\nDT BJS HKG 020209 M11A\r\n-  OFF,V01,KA 876 20170502 1,VHHH,ZSPD,0149,0208,----,  294', 'ACARS 20170507/20170505050124358002.rcv': 'QU SOUTA8X\r\n.BKKXCXA 050501\r\nCFD\r\nFI CX690/AN B-LAJ\r\nDT BKK XSP 050501 C10A\r\n-  .1/WRN/DBN17D/WN1705050500  261707002SMOKE LAVATORY DET FAULT'}]
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize(a)
```

Get a rdd with the keys:

```
>>> rdd_k = rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x.keys())
>>> rdd_k.take(3)
['ACARS 20170507/20170506085012209001.rcv', 'ACARS 20170507/20170505050124358002.rcv', 'ACARS 20170507/20170502020906017001.rcv']
```

Get a rdd with the values:

```
>>> rdd_v = rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x.values())
>>> rdd_v.take(3)
['QU SOUTA8X\r\n.BJSXCXA 060849\r\nM12\r\nFI CX731/AN B-LAN\r\nDT BJS HKG 060849 M63A\r\n-  OFF,V01,CX 731 20170506 1,VHHH,OMDB,0833,0849,----,  600', 'QU SOUTA8X\r\n.BKKXCXA 050501\r\nCFD\r\nFI CX690/AN B-LAJ\r\nDT BKK XSP 050501 C10A\r\n-  .1/WRN/DBN17D/WN1705050500  261707002SMOKE LAVATORY DET FAULT', 'QU SOUTA8X\r\n.BJSXCXA 020209\r\nM12\r\nFI KA876/AN B-LAB\r\nDT BJS HKG 020209 M11A\r\n-  OFF,V01,KA 876 20170502 1,VHHH,ZSPD,0149,0208,----,  294']
```

Zip the two rdds, you will have a rdd of tuples, every tuple is a pair (key,value) of your starting dictionary:

```
>>> newRdd = rdd_k.zip(rdd_v)
>>> newRdd.first()
('ACARS 20170507/20170506085012209001.rcv', 'QU SOUTA8X\r\n.BJSXCXA 060849\r\nM12\r\nFI CX731/AN B-LAN\r\nDT BJS HKG 060849 M63A\r\n-  OFF,V01,CX 731 20170506 1,VHHH,OMDB,0833,0849,----,  600')
```

Convert to dataframe:

```
>>> df = newRdd.toDF()
>>> df.show()
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                  _1|                  _2|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|ACARS 20170507/20...|QU SOUTA8X
.BJSX...|
|ACARS 20170507/20...|QU SOUTA8X
.BKKX...|
|ACARS 20170507/20...|QU SOUTA8X
.BJSX...|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that works for one dictionary first and then apply that to the RDD of dictionary.

```
helpin = [{'ACARS 20170507/20170506085012209001.rcv': 'QU SOUTA8X\r\n.BJSXCXA 060849\r\nM12\r\nFI CX731/AN B-LAN\r\nDT BJS HKG 060849 M63A\r\n-  OFF,V01,CX 731 20170506 1,VHHH,OMDB,0833,0849,----,  600', 'ACARS 20170507/20170502020906017001.rcv': 'QU SOUTA8X\r\n.BJSXCXA 020209\r\nM12\r\nFI KA876/AN B-LAB\r\nDT BJS HKG 020209 M11A\r\n-  OFF,V01,KA 876 20170502 1,VHHH,ZSPD,0149,0208,----,  294', 'ACARS 20170507/20170505050124358002.rcv': 'QU SOUTA8X\r\n.BKKXCXA 050501\r\nCFD\r\nFI CX690/AN B-LAJ\r\nDT BKK XSP 050501 C10A\r\n-  .1/WRN/DBN17D/WN1705050500  261707002SMOKE LAVATORY DET FAULT'}]

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession # convert rdd to dataframe
spark = SparkSession(sc)

def helpfunc(dicin):
    dicout = sc.parallelize(dicin).map(lambda x:(x,dicin[x])).toDF()
    return (dicout)


helpdic = helpin[0]
helpfunc(helpdic).show()
```

When actually helpin is an rdd, use:

```
helpin.map(lambda x:helpfunc(x))
```